# Lost connection to WatchKit App

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I am attempting to test my Watchkit app on a device. It worked perfectly on the simulator, however when I try to run it on my watch, it Xcode tells me it has loss connection to iPhone. I tried to "solution" where you go to Debugger->Attach to Process->WatchKit, but it still doesn't work. Xcode keeps losing connection. None of the other answers to related questions on stack overflow seem to be helping me, and this issue is becoming more stressful every second.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issues myself and got rid of them following these steps:

1. Disconnect your iPhone and reconnect it again.
2. Clean your project (cmd + K).
3. Close Xcode and open it again.
4. Run the host app on your phone.
5. Try to run the app on the watch again.

Hopes that helps for you, too.